# Rename file in Unix using part of the filename

Tags: file, unix, rename

How do I rename all files in a folder in Unix with part of the filename? Basically I want to use the string before the first hyphen to rename the file.

Current Filename Format:

```
ABC_XYZ-2022-11-09_07.52.03.csv
ABCD_XYZ-2022-11-09_07.52.03.csv
ABCDEF_XY-2022-11-09_07.52.03.csv
```

Desired format:

```
ABC_XYZ.csv
ABCD_XYZ.csv
ABCDEF_XY.csv
```

I am new in Unix and have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.csv
do
    mv -i "$i" "${i%%-*}".csv
done
```

`${i%%-*}` is the value of variable `i` with the longest string matching `-*` removed from its end. This also removes the `.csv` or any other `.*` ending.

I used `mv -i` to get a prompt in case the target file already exists. This could happen if two file names differ only in the date/time part.

If you have files with different endings you want to keep, a POSIX compatible solution might get a bit more complicated.

If all files contain a `.` after the part you want to remove and if you use `bash`, you can also use

```
for i in *
do
    mv -i "$i" "${i/-*./.}"
done
```